# Breakup and nest array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

What is the easiest method of making the `targetArray` categorized and look like the `desiredArray`?

```
var targetArray = ["volvo|car", "bmw|car", "suzuki|mc"];

var desiredArray = {
    "car" : {
        "volvo",
        "bmw",
        "audi"
    },
    "mc" : {
        "suzuki"
    }
};
```

Comment: Loop over `targetArray`.  `.split('|')` the value.  Check if the key exists in `desiredArray` and create it if it doesn't.  Add the value to the key.

Comment: P.S. Your `desiredArray` is actually an object and it's not valid syntax.  It would wind up being `desiredArray = {"mc": ["suzuki"]}`.

Comment: @halliewuud Why'd you delete that `classGroups` question? See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/dgpHY/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = {}

$.each(["volvo|car", "bmw|car", "suzuki|mc"], function(index, item){
  // split at pipe
  var split = item.split('|');
  // create array for car type if there is not already one
  if(!result[split[1]])result[split[1]] = [];
  // push to that array
  result[split[1]].push(split[0]);
});
```

Comment: There were a few typos in the code, I fixed it for you :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat thank you, I made it w/ `_.reduce` and I left the memo around ^^

Comment: Yeah, I figured something like that :)